# Django queryset - fetching reverse relations

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two models with a one-to-many relation through a `ForeignKey`. At some stage, I have obtained a queryset of the 'one' objects and would like to retrieve, as efficiently as possible, all of the 'many' objects that are associated with them. Here is a minimal example:

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    @classmethod
    def search(cls, keyword):
        return keyword_search_cars(cls, keyword)


class Passenger(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now I would like to query the models like so:

```py
# Get all passengers in cars matching term 'truck'
cars = Car.search('truck')
passengers = cars.passenger_set.all()  # Not permitted on querysets!
```

But the best I can come up with is something like this:

```py
car_ids = Car.search('truck').values_list('id', flat=True)
passengers = Passenger.objects.filter(car_id__in=car_ids)
```

With hundreds of records in the `cars` queryset, the `__in` filter seems like a dumb way to query the database. According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in), this does not do a SQL `JOIN` but instead writes a huge `WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, ... )` which does not seem optimal.

Does anyone know of a better approach for this? Currently my queries take 10+ seconds (with 1M+ records) which means rather poor performance for my application. It will get even slower as the database table grows in length.

For further context, the `Cars.search` method here can be considered an abstraction for full-text search with the `django.contrib.postgres.search` module (that's what my application is actually doing).

EDIT: show code for full text search method behind `Car.search()`:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.search import (
    SearchQuery,
    SearchRank,
    SearchVector,
)

RANK_THRESHOLD = 0.1


def keyword_search_cars(Model, query):
    vector = (
        SearchVector('name', weight='A')
        + SearchVector('description', weight='B')
    )
    query = SearchQuery(query)
    cars_results = (
        Model.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query))
        .filter(rank__gte=RANK_THRESHOLD)
        .order_by('-rank')
    )
    return cars_results
```

Comment: Can you show code in `keyword_search_cars ` method ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a backward filter lookup with [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to search for `keyword` in both fields of `Car` model:

```
Passenger.objects.filter(Q(car__name__contains=keyword) | Q(car__description__contains=keyword))
```

Comment: If this would capture the full text search (just added to post) and return the car instances too (maybe with `prefetch_related`?) then we'd be closer to solving the problem.

Comment: It does look for any string that is passed as param, as described in [contains field lookup documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#std-fieldlookup-contains). To access related models, in this case the `Cars` that `Passengers`  in this queryset are using `passengers.values('car__name').distinct()`. Note that if there is no `Passenger` inside a `Car` that matches `keyword` this will return empty.

Comment: That is true, but `__contains` doesn't allow for scoring and ranking as shown in my post. Your suggestion is useful though - I have built my `SearchQuery` around `Passenger` as you have described and I can access `Car` objects with `.select_related('car')`. If you can update your answer I'm happy to accept it!

Comment: Having said that, this solution seems to be 2x less performant than my original `filter(car_id__in=car_ids)` solution after I implemented at scale.

Comment: Another approach would be to use [database indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#performance) to speed up the query. [PostgreSQL source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX). If you can share data, I would be glad to help in finding a suitable solution.